# How to print a Email title and footer using java mail api?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have to set a few lines to be printed automatically as the Title and footer when ever i send a mail using the java mail api.
1.Kindly help to get these printed with no modification on my alignment.
2.How to set the background color to my email and how to set the font color for my email.
I have attached my java code and screen shots for mail.
Can any one Help me to achieve this?
Thanks in Advance.

**My java code of mailer:**

```
package comparexmlf1;
import comparexmlf1.validatexml;
import comparexmlf1.CarParser1;
import comparexmlf1.OrderParser2;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;   
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.swing.text.html.MinimalHTMLWriter;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeader;  
import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
public class mailer {
static void sendmail() throws IOException,     
MessagingException,AddressException
   {
          String to1=CarParser1.to1;
          DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy 
HH:mm:ss");
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String to2 = CarParser1.to2;
            String to3= CarParser1.to3;
            String to4=CarParser1.to4;
            String from = CarParser1.from;
            String host = CarParser1.host;
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); 
            int m_toterr,m_totwarn;
            String getfilepath="";
            String filenamechange="D:/newlog   
/"+CarParser1.si_orderid+"_log.txt";
            System.out.println("New File Path for mail:"+filenamechange);
            String pathLogFile = filenamechange;
            Enumeration enumeration =  
CarParser1.logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
            try {
                m_toterr=validatexml.Total_err;
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));   
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new 
InternetAddress(to1));

                message.setSubject(" CAR Validation Report at : 
"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())); 


                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    FileInputStream fstream = new 
FileInputStream(pathLogFile);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(fstream));

                    String singleLine;
                    while ((singleLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        sb.append(singleLine + "<br><br>");

                    }
                    br.close();
                    String allLines = sb.toString();

                  message.setContent(allLines, "text/html; charset=ISO-
8859-1");
                 Transport.send(message);



                System.out.println("Email Sent successfully....");
                CarParser1.logger.info("Email Sent Successfully...");
                System.out.println();

            } 
            catch (MessagingException mex) 
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Email Address.please provide 
a valid email id to send with");
                mex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

[image: Email Now Getting]

[image: Email Needed]

Can any one help me to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you send is rendered by the recipient's mail reader software.  If the recipient's mail reader supports HTML then you can send HTML email and control the content when you generate the HTML, including sending specific text/markup at the start and end of the message, and setting attributes like background color.

Whether or not all that has any effect will depend entirely on whether the recipient's mail reader software supports HTML.  It is generally advisable to provide a plain-text version as well for non-HTML readers.

There's nothing specific to Java email with regards to formatting, headers, footers or background color.  That has to do with HTML.

Comment: Thank you sir,Yes It supports HTML.Kindly help me with a sample code to print the same?

Comment: Kindly guide me with a sample code as i am new to this.